# Program To Test whether or not a 4x4 matrix is a magic square using functions in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, magic-square

Here is what I have.  I have it outputting most of the sums just so i can check there values. I think the problem is with the value of the elements in the array storing the column sums.
I would greatly appreciate any feedback.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void fillMatrix(int matrix[][4],const int SIZE);
int rowSum(int matrix[][4],const int SIZE,int row[]);
int columnSum(int matrix[][4], const int SIZE, int column[]);
bool isMagic(int matrix[][4], const int SIZE,int row[],int column[]);

int main()
{
const int SIZE=4;
int matrix[SIZE][SIZE];
int row[4],column[4];//arrays to be filled with row and column sums.
char response=0;

cout<<"This program determines whether or not a 4x4 square matrix is a magic square.\n";
do
{
    fillMatrix(matrix,SIZE);
    rowSum(matrix,SIZE,row);
    columnSum(matrix,SIZE,row);



    if(isMagic(matrix,SIZE,row,column))
        cout<<"This is a magic square.\n\n";
    else {
        cout<<"This is not a magic square.\n\n";
    }
    cout<<"To end this program, enter q. To check another matrix, enter any other letter.\n";
    cin>>response;
}while(response!='q'&&response!='Q');

return 0;
}

void fillMatrix(int matrix[][4],const int SIZE)
{
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    cout<<"Enter four values for row "<<i+1<<".\n";
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        cin>>matrix[i][j];
    }
}
}

int rowSum(int matrix[][4],const int SIZE,int row[4])
{ 
int i=0;
int rowsum=0;
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    rowsum=0;
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        rowsum+=matrix[i][j];
    }
   row[i]=rowsum;
    cout<<row[i]<<endl;
}
return row[i];

}
int columnSum(int matrix[][4], const int SIZE, int column[4])
{
int j=0;
int columnsum=0;
for(j=0;j<4;j++)
{
    columnsum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        columnsum+=matrix[i][j];
    }
    column[j]=columnsum;
    cout<<column[j]<<endl;
}
return column[j];
}

bool isMagic(int matrix[][4], const int SIZE,int row[4],int column[4])
{
int rightdiagonalsum=0, leftdiagonalsum=0, check;

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    rightdiagonalsum+=matrix[i][i];
}
cout<<rightdiagonalsum<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    leftdiagonalsum+=matrix[i][3-i];
}
cout<<leftdiagonalsum<<endl;
for(int i=1;i<4;i++)
{
    if (row[i]==row[i-1])
    {
        check=row[i];
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
{
    if (column[j]!=check)
    {
        cout<<column[j]<<"*****";//For some reason, the value of column[j] is 0.
        return false;
    }
}

if (rightdiagonalsum!=check||leftdiagonalsum!=check)
{
    return false;
}

return true;

}
```

Comment: If you are looking for comments on your code - and not a specific programming problem, you should post on code review - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
rowSum(matrix,SIZE,row);
columnSum(matrix,SIZE,row);
```

should be:

```
rowSum(matrix,SIZE,row);
columnSum(matrix,SIZE,column);
```

So the `column` array in your code has zero values for the rather mundane reason that you never initialised it.

What's more you are accessing beyond the end of the arrays here:

```
return row[i];
```

and here:

```
return column[j];
```

At both of these points `i` and `j` have values `4`. You would have avoided such a mistake had you declared the loop variables inside the `for` statement. That would have limited the scope of these variables.

To fix the problem, return `rowsum` and `columnsum` respectively.

I do wonder what purpose the various `SIZE` declarations serve since your hard code a value of 4 all over the place.

Comment: Thank you for the corrections.  I was able to fix the code in order to get the correct answer.  I began the code with the SIZE declarations so I could easily change the size of the matrix in the beginning for simple checks.  I have since edited the code.  Thank you for the helpful feedback!